# Syncadapter last update date

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

[image: AuthenticatorService]

How can obtain the last update date from the sync adapters services (marked with red) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  The API would (almost have to be) on `android.content.ContentResolver` as that's where periodic sync and enable/disable sync is managed.  There's no API there to request it.

Are you trying to find this value for your own SyncAdapter or for a third party app?

With your own SyncAdapter, you obviously can just store date() into a single-row sqlite table within your ContentProvider and reference it either from the SyncAdapter or the app.

For a third party app, that information... might not be avaliable?

Comment: Too me it looks like your using the term contentProvider incorrect, it should be SyncAdapter, right?

And, yes, i'm trying to find the last update value of the syncadapter of my app. At the moment, i'm storing the value in the database but if android allows me to read the value they store, I prefer that. I'm going to accept your awnser because I agree with you that android simply does not support it.